# class list returns empty DomTokens

Tags: javascript

//when i check if the list item has the className or not it returns false

`````
  sections.forEach(section => {
    const windowHeight =window.innerHeight;
  const sectionTop =section.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  const sectionReveal= 200;
  let current ='';
 
if(sectionTop<windowHeight-sectionReveal){
  section.classList.add('your-active-class');
  current= section.getAttribute('id');
  const myNav =document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
  console.log(myNav[1].classList.contains('menu__link'));
}
else{
  section.classList.remove('your-active-class');
}
});
  };
window.addEventListener('scroll',toggleSection);````
`````

Comment: You haven't shown your DOM (html structure), but getting `false` means that the second `<li>` in that `<ul>` simply doesn't ave the class `menu__link`. Why would you expect it to have one?

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll('ul li')` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). You should iterate all elements of it:

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(elem => { 
  if (elem.classList.contains('menu__link')) {
    /* do stuff to/with elem */} 
})`.
```

It may be easier to use `document.querySelector('ul li.menu__link')`.

Comment: it's not really clear what the OP even *wants* to do with these list elements, so no I don't think they should iterate them